# CI/CD on a production backend server

Tags: node.js, express, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm developing an app and I want to be able to quickly iterate on versions (fixing bugs and adding features, etc) so the obvious route to do this was to develop a CI/CD workflow. The frontend is simple enough, just swap out the assets my server serves with new builds, and as people access the site these assets will be served. However, I'm not so sure on how to go about updating my production backend servers, which are powered by express and node. In development, I can easily restart the server to reflect new changes, however doing this while in a production environment can have detrimental consequences for those who are using my service at the time of the update.

Overall, my question is what is the best way to push new backend server updates to my production environment without downtime/interrupting usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you'll want to run some sort of cluster of processes.

The first step behind this is ensuring your application is completely stateless and that you can have simultaneous copies of the express server running at the same time for load balancing.

If you do need to maintain some form of state, you can use an memory-based store such as Redis to share state amongst server instances.

Once you have such an architecture, you can direct and throttle traffic in a way that each server instance in the cluster gets a chance to restart with no traffic being directed towards it.

Say you have 4 instances running your server. You will turn instance 1 off, and your load balancing would send your traffic to 2, 3 and 4.

During this time, you can either hot reload or fully reload instance 1. You then turn instance 1 back on and repeat the process with 2, 3 and 4.

Such a process is called a "rolling update"

Comment: Ah ok, bear with me as I'm new to backend development, but I have a few more questions/clarifications. So I should have multiple server instances hooked up to my domain, and I'm assuming that will load balance, correct me if I'm wrong. Also I use passport to handle authentication, but I do have a database store for my sessions, so I'm assuming that by connecting these instances to the store then they can share authentication state? Other than that, my server just pulls things from the db/does computations on the fly, so I think I'm good there

Comment: Main thing to watch out for is if you're holding, and re-using variables between between requests within the application memory. Imagine your API request generates a number - 5- and stores it as generatedNumber. Then another API request tries to access the generated number to return it. In that case, you'd need to store such a variable in something like Redis temporarily to allow all instances to access it. As for load balancing, there's many solutions for that. Look into using Nginx in front of your application https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-unit-updating-apps-with-100-percent-uptime/

Comment: To clarify, that link is about implementing an approach similar to the one described in the answer for rolling updates. You can also use Nginx to have multiple "listeners" to load balance your traffic and achieve a similar outcome too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my API only shares a memory var once or twice between endpoints and that's just to hold temp user data during registration before committing it to my database. I'll look into Redis for that then. Also, thanks for the link I'll definitely look into that, although typically I'm not the biggest fan of nginx

Comment: You should also be using pm2 or a similar process manager to run 1 instance per CPU core. Normally Node runs on a single core so this will greatly improve your performance by balancing the load across all cores. You could utilise that instead of Nginx with a single VPS to achieve the same result :)  At least until you outgrow the performance or location limitations of a single VPS https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

Comment: I'm familiar with PM2, but I'm worried about duplicate responses. When running in cluster mode and my user makes a request to my server, will the server send multiple responses? that's happened to me before with developing discord bots, where my bot would respond several times to a command

Comment: Perhaps multiple instances of the bot running are causing it to re-read the same commands from the users and respond individually. So the request itself isn't duplicated across clusters, but the bot listeners may be? In that case you may want to use some form of central process queue separate to the express instances and prune duplicate responses - at least as a hacky, quick solution. Maybe you can check the incoming message ID or something in the process queue, and remove any jobs that that have the same ID as a message thta was recently responded to (maybe stored for 5 seconds, etc)

Comment: My service is not related to a discord bot, but I was just referencing an issue I've had in the past. I was mainly wondering whether or not this issue would occur with express/api requests/responses, where each instance of my server is listening for requests?

Comment: It shouldn't do that, no :). It will route each request to the currently least used instance of the server. At least, I believe that's how it works. In practice, you won't see any duplication like that.